# Xcode 8 auto generated Core Data stack is not supported with iOS 9 and below

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode8

Title explains the exact problem. Basic CoreData master detail template is only works on iOS 10 and above. But if you try to run the same template on iOS 9 or below it will crash because the `persistentContainer` was not created, which we used to get `NSManagedObjectContext`. This is due to latest iOS 10 addition with xCode 8. I saw there are few workarounds for Swift but not for Objective-C. Any better solution for Objc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution,

Since in iOS 9 and above does not have `persistentContainer` infrastructure basically you have to initialize core data stack by yourself like this,

put this method anywhere in your delegate class, This is what we have been doing prior to iOS 10 `persistentContainer` introduction.

```
- (void)initializeCoreData
{

    NSDictionary *options = @{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"}};

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"yourmodelname" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    NSAssert(mom != nil, @"Error initializing Managed Object Model");

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];
    _managedObjectContext = moc;
    [EFLDatabase sharedDatabaseWithManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *documentsURL = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    NSLog(@"DOC %@", [documentsURL absoluteString]);
    NSURL *storeURL = [documentsURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourmodelname.sqlite"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[self managedObjectContext] persistentStoreCoordinator];
        NSPersistentStore *store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error];
        NSAssert(store != nil, @"Error initializing PSC: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    });
}
```

Now put below snippet into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, which will basically checks the iOS version if below 10, then executes the above method,

```
if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersion].majorVersion < 10) {
        [self initializeCoreData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Download Xcode 7, create a project from the template and check *use core data*, and copy the Core Data stack from the App Delegate

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tried it, But unfortunately it does not worked for me.

Comment: When you say " it does not worked for me", what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well, It did not called `managedObjectContext` method automatically to proceed with the context creation.